# Skype, ICQ, Telegram icons are no longer displayed on Top Panel for Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: 18.04, icons, system-tray

It looks like some Ubuntu 18.04 update disable all non-system apps Tray Icons. Now those apps that should be minimized by clicking close <kbd>(x)</kbd> title bar's button. In this list all my apps with system tray icons like: Skype, ICQ, Telegram. + No any status indications.

Example:

[image: Top Bar, Top Panel, Dash, Skype]

As you can see is no Skype icon on example above.

Comment: No problems on my just updated 18.04.  How have you altered your title bar (like how did you make the on/off circle appear there, instead of in the dropdown)?

Comment: @ubfan1, 'on/off circle' - what you mean? If you mean is no battery icon,.. This is not a laptop.

Comment: The circle with a line at the top, second from left, between the speaker icon and the dropdown triangle.  The normal location is at the bottom-right of the dropdown list, so the defaults have been changed.  Look to where the change was made, maybe a clue to what's wrong.  Could the language dropdown be concealing your other icons (i don't have it on mine) ?  Do you get the skype menu on the left of the title bar (with just a quit)?

Comment: @ubfan1 Yes, Skype menu with Quit item is here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Partially fixed for Skype and Telegram.

1. I install this Gnome Extension: [KStatusNotifierItem/AppIndicator Support](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/) . Now I see Skype icon:

[image: Skype Top Panel Icon]

2. I go to Telegram Settings -> Advanced and enable **Show Tray Icon** from System Integration:

[image: Show Tray Icon]

[image: Telegram Top Panel Icon]

Now I see both icons for Telegram and Skype. Both applications continue work after closing by `(x)` close button on app window top panel. BTW ICQ not show Sys Icon, but also have same behavior like Skype and Telegram by close button click (continue working).

Answer (score 2):

step 1: check whether you are using the tweak tool. If not then install that first.

step 2: install a package named `chrome-gnome-shell`. For that you just have to fire a command `sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell`

step 3: go to https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/
and you will find on/off toggle. toggle on, and the issue will be gone.
[image]

Comment: as of april 2022, this fix still works, thanks